# Error When i try show popUp Modal Bootstrap in asp net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

The Modal in HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="ventanaNotificacion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <%--Controles--%>
            <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                <label class="text-center" id="lblIdNotificacion"></label>
            </div>

            <%--Footer--%>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button runat="server" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn btn-default">Salir</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Function:

```
<script>
        function abrirNotificacion(mensaje) {
            var _mensaje = mensaje;
           $('#ventanaNotificacion').modal('show')
           document.getElementById('lblIdNotificacion').innerHTML = _mensaje;
        }

    </script>
```

Im excecuting this from the code behind of my win form:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", " abrirNotificacion('" + mensaje + "');", true);
```

The problem result is in the "Show":  Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function.
I dont under stend why this not found. Any Help?

Comment: Make sure that bootstap js is loaded before your javascript

Comment: did you include `jquery` then `Bootstrap` js files in your .aspx pags

Comment: Yes, it is include in the master page. Now i'm including in the web form and i not has an error but not show me the modal